# sql server daily average

Tags: sql-server-2008, average

What's the best way to get a daily average.
The data would have 2 values per day, for example:

```
Date             Value
1/1/2012 4:00    10.00
1/1/2012 16:00   11.00
1/2/2012 4:00    11.22
1/2/2012 16:00   13.55
etc.
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Select CAST(DateColumn as date), AVG(Value)
From Table
Group By CAST(DateColumn as date)
```

Comment: This won't work if some value is not exist in certain date while others is exist

Answer (score 3):

```
select date, avg(value)
from yourTable
group by date
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select
 cast(Date as date),
 avg(Value)
from 
 Table
group by cast(Date as date)
```